# BeautifulSoup html -- load from memory?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using `BeautifulSoup` in python 3.5 to parse html. While I can load it from file, I need to load it from memory because I get from an HTTP request. I've google but found nothing loading html to BeautifulSoup from memory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the version 4 of BeautifulSoup, try passing the request data to it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# replace the following URL
response = requests.get("https://www.python.org")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

data = requests.get('https://google.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```